# Send Emails on a button click from salesforce through SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to send the data on a button click to SFMC and then send Emails from it. I have created 1 triggered Send and 1 Data Extension in SFMC. I was stucked on how to start with sending the data to it. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

There's a number of similar posts/questions/solutions of triggering an email from Salesforce : here is one that has worked for myself.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BJ72IAG

Comment: The question is about Salesforce Marketing Cloud not Salescloud, therefore this answer does not work for the SFMC environment.